# fancybox transition

Tags: jquery, fancybox

How can I change the default transition of all fancybox in my pages?
Because I don't want to have transition effects on my fancyboxes but it's a bother to set them in each and every fancybox codes.

and this code is not possible

```
$.("*").fancybox({
        'transitionIn'      : 'none',
        'transitionOut'     : 'none' 
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to avoid setting the transitions in each Fancybox initialisation, you could just change the defaults in the core Fancybox script - they will be set in there. See `$.fn.fancybox.defaults` near the bottom of the script

Answer (score 2):

If you have a class assigned to all your fancyboxes you could do

```
 $('.fancybox').fancybox({'transitionIn': 'none', 'transitionOut': 'none'});
```

Or change the fancybox defaults by extending the fancybox defaults with something like this:

```
 $.fn.fancybox.defaults = {
      transitionIn: 'none',
      transitionOut: 'none'
 };
```

Comment: Setting defaults like this you will overwrite all other default settings leaving only `transitionIn` and `transitionOut`

Comment: @dsfq Isn't that what we're going for here? To globally change a few of the default values for all slideshows across the site?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting those options this way:

```
$.fn.fancybox.defaults = $.extend($.fn.fancybox.defaults, {
    transitionIn: 'none',
    transitionOut: 'none'
});
```

Comment: It doesn't really matter where. For example in the beggining of your script (but after `<script src="fancybox.js">` of course). For example, go to the Fancybox official site, and execute this code in the debug console. And see how demos will behave after that.